# Why isn't my program assigning variables to the object, and then calculating from it?

Tags: javascript, function, oop, variables

This assignment is to take a pizza order and build one. Once the pizza is assembled, it should calculate the total cost of the pizza and spit out the total answer. I've played around on JsFiddle.net for two days now and can't figure out why it won't get past the interrogate function and move on to the calculate. I've entered in a couple alert statements here and there and still can't figure out what's going on. My best guess is either that 'myPizza' properties are not being assigned or that they are not being shared by the other functions. I know the second possibility could not be true because 'myPizza' is a global object with global properties.

```
recycle = true; 
var ingrediants = ['pepperoni ', 'sausage ', 'avocado ', 'chicken ', 'mushrooms ', 'anchovies ', 'bacon ', 'pineapple ', 'beeswax '];
var toppings=[];
var i = -1;

var myPizza= {
    size:"",
    toppings:[],
    stuffCrust:false,
    sodaSide: false
};

var greeting = function () {
    wantPizza = prompt("Hello! Welcome to Sean's Pizza Shack! Would you like to order a pizza?(Yes or No?)").toLowerCase();
    if (wantPizza === 'yes') {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("Okay then, Get out of my pizza shop because I have customers waiting");
        return false;
    }
};

var interrogate = function () {
    myPizza.size = prompt("Okay sir/Ma'am, Would you like a Small, Medium, Large, or extra Large?(XL)").toLowerCase();
    myPizza.toppings = prompt("Alright! So what would you like on your " + myPizza.size + " pizza?" + " We have " + ingrediants).toLowerCase();

    do { 
        i = i + 1;
        myPizza.toppings+= toppings[i] =prompt(ingrediants + " Please type one ingrediant at a time to add to your pizza! or you may enter 'ALL' to add all toppings or press OK without entry to stop adding toppings").toLowerCase();
    } while (toppings[i] !== "");

    //LOOP TO DECIDE IF NEED TO PUSH ALL INGREDIENTS 
    for (k = 0; k <toppings.length; k++) {
        if (toppings[k] === 'all') {
            toppings = [];
            toppings.push(ingrediants);
        } else {
            toppings.length -= 1; // IF NOT ALL INGREDIENTS, SUBTRACT '' FROM     ADD INGREDIENTS //LOOP
        }
    }
    alert("So you would like " + myPizza.toppings + " on your pizza!");
    alert("Okay so i have a " + myPizza.size + " pizza, with " + myPizza.toppings + "!");
    myPizza.stuffCrust = prompt("Do you want your pizza to have extra delicious stuffed cheesy crust?($4.00)").toLowerCase();
    if(myPizza.stuffCrust==='yes') {
        myPizza.stuffCrust=true;
    }
    myPizza.sodaSide = prompt("Would you like a 2 Liter soda with that for an extra $2.00?");
    if(myPizza.sodaSide=== yes) {
        myPizza.sodaSide=true;
    }
    alert(myPizza.sodaSide);
    alert(myPizza.toppings);
    alert(myPizza.stuffCrust);
    alert(myPizza.toppings.length);
};

var up= {
    total:0,
    Sm:9.00,
    Med:12.00,
    Lrg: 15.00,
    XL: 18.00,
    Top: myPizza.toppings.length*1.00,
    Stuff:4.00,
    Soda: 2.00,
    add: function(input) {
        total+=input;
    }
};       

var calculate= function() {
    switch(myPizza.size) {
    case 'small': up.add(up.Sm);break;
    case 'medium': up.add(up.Med);break;
    case 'large': up.add(up.Lrg);break;
    case 'XL': up.add(up.XL);break;
    }
    if(myPizza.toppings.length>0) {
        up.add(up.Top);
    } if (myPizza.stuffCrust) {
        up.add(up.Stuff);
    } if (myPizza.sodaSide) {
        up.add(up.Soda);
    }
    alert("Okay, looks like your order comes to "+ up.total);
};

var main= function () {
    if (greeting() === true) {
        interrogate();
        calculate();
    }
};

main();
```

Comment: maybe you could start by: 
indenting your code, jsFiddle, isolating your bug (not putting the whole thing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the statement:

```
if(myPizza.sodaSide=== yes) {
    myPizza.sodaSide=true;
}
```

you need to have `yes` in quotes:

```
if(myPizza.sodaSide=== 'yes') {
    myPizza.sodaSide=true;
}
```